# How can I use the mathematical constant e in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I want to calculate a mathematical function which will use the mathematical constant e, and I don't know how to use e, like `Math.e`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solidity doesn't support floating-point arithmetic.

You'll need to represent `e` with a pair of an integer numerator and an integer denominator.

For example:

```
uint256 eN = 271828;
uint256 eD = 100000;
```

Then, you'll need to replace every plan for `x * e` in your code with `x * eN / eD`.

In order to achieve maximum accuracy while reducing the number of erroneous computations to minimum, set the highest possible value of `eN` (and then set `eD` accordingly), such that `maxX * eN` in your program is smaller than 2 ^ 256.

Also for maximum accuracy, keep in mind that you should try to postpone the `/ eD` part as much as possible.

For example, change `x * eN / eD + y` to `(x * eN + y * eD) / eD`.

Of course, the condition of `maxX * eN` being smaller than 2 ^ 256 changes to `x * eN + y * eD` being smaller than 2 ^ 256.

Alternatively to all of that, you can replace every `x * y` in your code with `x.mul(y)` (see an example implementation of function `mul` in [OpenZeppelin's SafeMath Library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol)).

But beware that this will:

1. Replace every erroneous computation with the transaction being reverted
2. Increase the gas cost of every computation which makes use of multiplication

---

Here is a short Python 3 snippet for the "offline" calculation of `eN` and `eD` given `maxX`:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from decimal import getcontext

getcontext().prec = 100

def getBestE(maxX):
    e = Decimal(1).exp()
    eD = int((2**256-1)/(e*maxX))
    eN = int(eD*e)
    return eN,eD
```

You can run it once, and then define those two constants in your code.

Of course, you can use different pairs of `eN` and `eD` for different computations (it's all a question of how "dirty" you're willing your code to be in favor of optimizing accuracy and/or performance).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it completely solved my question.This is the first time that i post a question, and get a very complete solution, it feels me so good.Finally wish you have fun in your life

Comment: @user6391810: Hahaha. Thank you, glad you've enjoyed the answer :)